# Mysql query to fetch the same datetime values

Tags: mysql, datetime

Hii Guys!!!
               I have a table in which there is a column named "Calldate" which contains datetime value.Now in this column so many rows are there which have the same date and time value.So i need to retrieve those values from the table.

Plz guys help me to complete the task ..
Thanx in advance.

Comment: So you need those rows which have duplicate values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Select 
* 
from table1 
inner join 
(
Select 
Calldate
from table 
group by Calldate 
having count(*)>1
) 
as temp_table on (table1.Calldate=temp_table.Calldate)
```

Answer (score 1):

If u only want to retrieve the duplicate date and time value, then the answer should be:

```
SELECT Calldate, 
COUNT(Calldate) FROM table 
GROUP BY Calldate 
HAVING COUNT(Calldate) > 1
```

This will return the record which has duplicate date and time; with the total duplicated records of a date and time

Answer (score 0):

```
        The DATETIME values contain both date and time. MySQL retrieves and displays values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is from '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

        you may write the query as follows:

       to get all values:
        select Calldate from tableName

       to get the one record among multiple same records:
        select distinct(Calldate) from tableName

      to get the same valued records from column:

select Calldate from tableName
group by Calldate
Having count(Calldate)>1
```